# Angularjs ui-select2 formatSelection format to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select2

I'm using ui-select2 to add multiple items (tag mode). when adding an item I want to show inside the input some special ui, so I want to add some directive.
trying to use formatSelection to format the input:

```
function colorFormat(state) {
   return '<color-selection selections="option.selections"></color-selection>';
}
```

but the directive did not compiled. So I compiled it:

```
function colorFormat(state) {
  return $compile('<color-selection selections="option.selections"></color-selection>')(scope);
}
```

but now, the value is ['object object']. it appears that the format is stringing my result. so how do I format to directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so formatSelection os not expecting html, but jqlite/angular object. but it converts it to string. so one solution is to remove the convert and just append the given element.
another solution is that formatSelection is called with the container element as the second parameter:

```
formatSelection(state, container) {
  container.append($compile('bla')(scope));
}
```

don't return anything, just append your result.

Answer (score 0):

formatSelection expects html in return and $compile service will return objects.
In my opinion, You will need to compile the elements and get the html string.

Try this.

```
  var compiledHTML = $compile('<color-selection selections="option.selections"></color-selection>')(scope);
    $timeout(function(){

        var formatString = '';
        for(i=0; i<compiledHTML.length; i++)
            formatString += compiledHTML[i].outerHTML;

        return formatString ;
    },0);
```

Also if it does not work, it would be better if you can create a small plunkr or fiddle which can help in debugging.